# C++, Find out if a string contains a substring?

Tags: c++, string, find

I don't know how to use the find() function to check if a string contains a substring, then the program should print out all Words, and "Contains" if Sentence contains at least one of them. Can anyone help me out? My usage of find() sets A always to true. Thanks for help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string Words, Sentence, buf;
int i, n, j = 0;
string arr[20];
bool A;

int main() {

cout << "Words separated by slashes";
cin >> Words;
cout << "Sentence";
cin >> Sentence;

for (i = 0; i <= Words.length(); i++)
{
if (Words[i] != '/')    
{
    buf = buf + Words[i];
}
else
{  
    arr[n] = buf;
    n = n + 1;
    buf = "";
 } 
 }
 for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
 { 
 cout << arr[j] << "\n";

 if (Sentence.find(arr[j]) != string::npos)
 {
     A = true;
  }
 }  
 if (A == true)
 {
 cout << "Contains.";
 }
 else
 {
 enter code herecout << "Does not contain.";
  }
 }
```

Comment: The loop `for (i = 0; i <= Words.length(); i++)` will go out of bounds of `Words`. Also remember that e.g. `cin >> Sentence` will not actually read a sentence, as it stops on space.

Comment: I see nothing in your code that ever *explicitly* sets `A` to `false`.

Comment: What's more, you never initialize `n` so when you first use it, its value will be *indeterminate* and lead to *undefined behavior*. And the next loop (`for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)`) will *also* go out of bounds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `n` is a global and therefore initialised to zero.

Comment: @john Oh yeah, didn't really notice that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few bugs and issues in this code I think, but the biggest is the for loops all go too far by one.

```
for (i = 0; i <= Words.length(); i++)
```

and

```
for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i < Words.length(); i++)
```

and

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
```

The valid indexes for a string, vector or array are zero upto **but not including** the size of the string, vector or array.

This mistake causes the bug that you see. Suppose you have two words in `arr`, e.g. `arr = { "stack", "overflow", "", "", ... }` . Because you go around the for loop one too many times you end up searching for `arr[2]` which equals `""`. This search always succeeds because every string contains the empty string. And so you always set `A` to true.

Comment: `Words[Words.length()]` is valid and defined since C++11. But the second loop is probably the root cause indeed.